Java POST to Python FastApi - JSON payload - Unprocessable entity?
I'm attempting to make a POST request to a FastApi from a Java front-end. I have tried several different things I have found reading online, but I cannot make it work.
Java implementation:
public JSONObject saveData(JSONObject data) {
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    try {
        HttpClient client = newHttpClient();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(apiUrl + "save_variants"))
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(data.toString()))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response =
                client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        String jsonString = response.body().replaceAll("\\\\","");
        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    System.out.println("Received updated data:" + jsonResponse);

    return jsonResponse;
}

Python FastApi post:
class Item(BaseModel):
    item: str


@app.post("/variants")
async def save_variants(item: Item):
    logger.info(f"Payload:${item}")

    return read_param_json("variant_parameters_original.json")

On FastApi side:

I can't seem to get the correct data passed to FastApi, or get FastApi to read it correctly - unsure where the problem is exactly.
I tried this: How to make a JSON POST request from Java client to Python FastAPI server?, same error
EDIT:
Request response:

Received updated data:{"detail":[{"msg":"Field required","loc":["body"],"input":null,"type":"missing"}]}


The body of the 422 response will have exact information about what is missing or what isn't being parsed properly. Since you didn't include what your request looks like, it'll be hard for anyone to say what you're sending or not sending. I'm guessing you might need to set the Content-Type header of your request to application/json to indicate you're sending JSON as well?

@MatsLindh response added to question.
I tried setting Content-Type too and no change to the problem

"body", "missing", and "input":null seems to indicate that there is no data being submitted; did you verify what data you're submitting and that you configured the content-type correctly?

@MatsLindh the json data in the Java is correct going into the POST.
If I remove the logging from the FastApi post function, I get a different error:
Invalid HTTP request received.
I can't seem to log what the server is receiving without it falling over

The "Invalid HTTP request received" should indicate that whatever your Java application is sending does not have a valid HTTP POST body according to its other parameters, so inspecting what actually gets sent between the client and the server seems to be the relevant part

So I wrote a basic example from the post mentioned in the question and it worked (Java POST to Python FastApi - JSON payload - Unprocessable entity?)
I realised that the item has a member item, who's value needs to be the payload I am sending.
Solved by:
In Java:
jsonInputString = "{\"payload\": \"" + jsonInputString + "\"}";

In the Python:
class User(BaseModel):
    payload: str


@app.post("/variants")
def main(user: User):
    json_obj = json.loads(user.payload)
    logger.warning(f"Received:${json_obj}")

    with open("variant_parameters.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(json_obj))

